# Pass python IplImage object as simple struct to shared C library using ctypes

Tags: python, opencv, interface, wrapper, ctypes

I'm trying to create a python wrapper for application written in C/C++ which make extensive use of OpenCV C API. I would like to use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) for this, because I have used it successfully in previous programmes. But I have come to problems when trying to pass IplImage from Python as parameter to functions in c library.

I have created a sample test library to demonstrate the problem. Here are the functions from library which I would like to use:

```
// ImageDll.h

#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

extern "C"  //Tells the compile to use C-linkage for the next scope.
{
    // Returns image loaded from location
    __declspec(dllexport) IplImage* Load(char* dir);

    // Show image
    __declspec(dllexport) void Show(IplImage* img);
}
```

And a cpp file:

```
// ImageDll.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc /LD

#include "ImageDll.h"

using namespace std;

extern "C"  //Tells the compile to use C-linkage for the next scope.
{
    IplImage* Load(char* dir)
    {
        return cvLoadImage(dir, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    }

    void Show(IplImage* img)
    {
        cvShowImage("image", img);
        cvWaitKey(0);
    }
}
```

And here is the initial attempt in python:

```
from time import sleep
from ctypes import *
from modules.acquisition import InitCamera, GetImage
from modules.utils import struct
import cv2.cv as cv

# load DLL containing image functions
print "Loading shared library with genetic algorithm...",
image_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("OpenCV_test_DLL.dll")
print "Done."
# get function handles
print "Loading functions of library...",
image_load = image_lib.Load
image_show = image_lib.Show
# set return type for functions (because ctypes default is int)
image_load.restype = c_void_p
image_show.restype = None
print "Done."

# initialize source
print "Initializing camera",
source = struct()
InitCamera(source)
print "Done."

# show video
while (1):
    # get image as PIL image
    img = GetImage(source)
    # transform image to OpenCV IplImage
    cv_img = cv.CreateImageHeader(img.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
    cv.SetData(cv_img, img.tostring())
    # show image using OpenCV highgui lib
    image_show(pointer(cv_img))
```

As you can see, I am getting images from camera as PIL images, which I then convert to python IplImage. This works for 100% because when I replace last line **image_show(pointer(cv_img))** with python bindings from cv2.cv module:

```
    cv.ShowImage("image", cv_img)
    cv.WaitKey(20)
```

then I get correct output.

So the problem is with **image_show(pointer(cv_img))** which fails with **TypeError: *type* must have storage info**. This is because cv_img needs to be valid ctypes IplImage structure. I have tried to mimic it with ctypes with little success:

```
from ctypes import *
from cv2 import cv

# ctypes IplImage
class cIplImage(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("nSize", c_int),
                ("ID", c_int),
                ("nChannels", c_int),
                ("alphaChannel", c_int),
                ("depth", c_int),
                ("colorModel", c_char * 4),
                ("channelSeq", c_char * 4),
                ("dataOrder", c_int),
                ("origin", c_int),
                ("align", c_int),
                ("width", c_int),
                ("height", c_int),
                ("roi", c_void_p),
                ("maskROI", c_void_p),
                ("imageID", c_void_p),
                ("tileInfo", c_void_p),
                ("imageSize", c_int),
                ("imageData", c_char_p),
                ("widthStep", c_int),
                ("BorderMode", c_int * 4),
                ("BorderConst", c_int * 4),
                ("imageDataOrigin", c_char_p)]
```

Here is the function which does the conversion:

```
# convert Python PIL to ctypes Ipl
def PIL2Ipl(input_img):

    # mode dictionary:
    # (pil_mode : (ipl_depth, ipl_channels)
    mode_list = {
        "RGB" : (cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3),
        "L"   : (cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1),
        "F"   : (cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
        }

    if not mode_list.has_key(input_img.mode):
        raise ValueError, 'unknown or unsupported input mode'

    result = cIplImage()
    result.imageData = c_char_p(input_img.tostring())
    result.depth = c_int(mode_list[input_img.mode][0])
    result.channels = c_int(mode_list[input_img.mode][1])
    result.height = c_int(input_img.size[0])
    result.width = c_int(input_img.size[1])

    return result
                    ("imageData", c_char_p),
                    ("widthStep", c_int),
                    ("BorderMode", c_int * 4),
                    ("BorderConst", c_int * 4),
                    ("imageDataOrigin", c_char_p)]
```

Video loop then changes to

```
# show video
while (1):
    # get image as PIL image
    img = GetImage(source)
    # transform image to OpenCV IplImage
    cv_img = cIplImage()
    cv_img = PIL2Ipl(img)
    # show image using OpenCV highgui lib
    image_show(pointer(cv_img))
```

This way the data get passed to library, but then it cries for **OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in unknown function**. So created ctypes structure is not valid. Does anyone know how to implement it correctly? I would accept even other solution not using ctypes when it enables me to get *python IplImage passed to c library*. Thanks.

**NOTE:** I have tried to find answer for this question for last 2 days without any success. There are solutions for OpenCV 1.0 but with recent OpenCV bindings for Python which use numpy arrays it is almost impossible to make interfaces between Python and C applications work. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have found solution to my problem. Instead of using default python functions

```
cv.CreateImageHeader()
cv.SetData()
```

I used C functions exported from OpenCV C library. :) I even managed to flip colors from PILs RGB to IplImage BGR format. Here is the full source:

**ImageDll.h**

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

extern "C"  //Tells the compile to use C-linkage for the next scope.
{
    // Returns image loaded from location
    __declspec(dllexport) IplImage* Load(char* dir);

    // Show image
    __declspec(dllexport) void Show(IplImage* img);

    // Auxiliary functions
    __declspec(dllexport) void aux_cvSetData(CvArr* arr, void* data, int step);
    __declspec(dllexport) IplImage* aux_cvCreateImageHeader(int width, int height, int depth, int channels);
    __declspec(dllexport) IplImage* aux_cvCvtColor(const IplImage* src, int code);
    __declspec(dllexport) void aux_cvCopy(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst);
    __declspec(dllexport) void aux_cvReleaseImage(IplImage** image);
    __declspec(dllexport) void aux_cvReleaseImageHeader(IplImage** image);
}
```

**ImageDll.cpp**

```
#include "ImageDll.h"

using namespace std;

extern "C"  //Tells the compile to use C-linkage for the next scope.
{
    IplImage* Load(char* dir)
    {
        return cvLoadImage(dir, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    }

    void Show(IplImage* img)
    {
        cvShowImage("image", img);
        cvWaitKey(5);
    }

    void aux_cvSetData(CvArr* arr, void* data, int step)
    {
        cvSetData(arr,data,step);
    }

    IplImage* aux_cvCreateImageHeader(int width, int height, int depth, int channels)
    {
        return cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(width,height), depth, channels);
    }

    IplImage* aux_cvCvtColor(const IplImage* src, int code)
    {
        IplImage* dst = cvCreateImage(cvSize(src->width,src->height),src->depth,src->nChannels);
        cvCvtColor(src, dst, code);
        return dst;
    }

    void aux_cvCopy(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst)
    {
        cvCopy(src, dst, NULL);
    }

    void aux_cvReleaseImage(IplImage** image)
    {
        cvReleaseImage(image);
    }

    void aux_cvReleaseImageHeader(IplImage** image)
    {
        cvReleaseImageHeader(image);
    }
}
```

**run.py**

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8

from time import sleep
from ctypes import *
from modules.acquisition import InitCamera, GetImage
from modules.utils import struct
import cv2.cv as cv
from modules.ipl import *

# load DLL containing image functions
print "Loading shared library with C functions...",
image_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("OpenCV_test_DLL.dll")
print "Done."
# get function handles
print "Loading functions of library...",
image_load = image_lib.Load
image_show = image_lib.Show
cvReleaseImage = image_lib.aux_cvReleaseImage
# set return type for functions (because ctypes default is int)
image_load.restype = c_void_p
image_show.restype = None
cvReleaseImage.restype = None
print "Done."

# initialize source
print "Initializing camera",
source = struct()
InitCamera(source)
print "Done."

# show video
while (1):
    # get image as PIL image
    img = GetImage(source)
    # transform image to OpenCV IplImage
    cv_img = PIL2Ipl(img)
    # show image using OpenCV highgui lib
    image_show(cv_img)
    # release memory
    cvReleaseImage(byref(cv_img))
```

**ipl.py**

```
from ctypes import *
from cv2 import cv

# ctypes IplImage
class cIplImage(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("nSize", c_int),
                ("ID", c_int),
                ("nChannels", c_int),
                ("alphaChannel", c_int),
                ("depth", c_int),
                ("colorModel", c_char * 4),
                ("channelSeq", c_char * 4),
                ("dataOrder", c_int),
                ("origin", c_int),
                ("align", c_int),
                ("width", c_int),
                ("height", c_int),
                ("roi", c_void_p),
                ("maskROI", c_void_p),
                ("imageID", c_void_p),
                ("tileInfo", c_void_p),
                ("imageSize", c_int),
                ("imageData", POINTER(c_char)),
                ("widthStep", c_int),
                ("BorderMode", c_int * 4),
                ("BorderConst", c_int * 4),
                ("imageDataOrigin", c_char_p)]

# load DLL containing needed OpenCV functions
libr = cdll.LoadLibrary("OpenCV_test_DLL.dll")
cvSetData = libr.aux_cvSetData
cvCreateImageHeader = libr.aux_cvCreateImageHeader
cvCvtColor = libr.aux_cvCvtColor
cvCopy = libr.aux_cvCopy
cvReleaseImage = libr.aux_cvReleaseImage
cvReleaseImageHeader = libr.aux_cvReleaseImageHeader
# set return types for library functions
cvSetData.restype = None
cvCreateImageHeader.restype = POINTER(cIplImage)
cvCvtColor.restype = POINTER(cIplImage)
cvCopy.restype = None
cvReleaseImage.restype = None
cvReleaseImageHeader.restype = None
#print "auxlib loaded"

# convert Python PIL to ctypes Ipl
def PIL2Ipl(pil_img):
    """Converts a PIL image to the OpenCV/IplImage data format.

    Supported input image formats are:
        RGB
        L
        F
    """

    # mode dictionary:
    # (pil_mode : (ipl_depth, ipl_channels)
    mode_list = {
        "RGB" : (cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3),
        "L"   : (cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1),
        "F"   : (cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1)
        }

    if not mode_list.has_key(pil_img.mode):
        raise ValueError, 'unknown or unsupported input mode'

    depth = c_int(mode_list[pil_img.mode][0])
    channels = c_int(mode_list[pil_img.mode][1])
    height = c_int(pil_img.size[1])
    width = c_int(pil_img.size[0])
    data = pil_img.tostring()

    ipl_img = cvCreateImageHeader(width, height, depth, channels);
    cvSetData(ipl_img, create_string_buffer(data,len(data)), c_int(width.value * channels.value))
    brg_img = cvCvtColor(ipl_img,cv.CV_RGB2BGR)
    cvReleaseImageHeader(byref(ipl_img))
    return brg_img
```

Hope it will help someone :)